# How to replace text from a source file into different files

Tags: file, batch-file, notepad++

So I have been using *Notepad++* to do some little clean-up tasks and now I am left with the biggest task..

I have a file called `Artists.txt` which looks like

```
Butta Mohamed
Daler Mehndi
Daljit Mattu
Darshan Khela
Davinder Deep
Davinder Deol
etc...
```

I have another file called `Keywords.txt` (located in hundreds of other folders). The folders are named like below and they all contain a text file called Keywords.txt

```
butta-mohamed-lyrics
daler-mehndi-lyrics
daljit-mattu-lyrics
darshan-khela-lyrics
davinder-deep-lyrics
davinder-deol-lyrics
```

The Keywords.txt contains the text _1 (several instances within the Keywords.txt).

What I would like to do is get each line from `Artists.txt` and have the _1 replaced. The folders are in the same order as Artists.txt.

So read Artists.txt get first line Butta Mohamed get first folder butta-mohamed-lyrics edit Keywords.txt find _1 replace (all) with Butta Mohamed. Save changes. Rinse and repeat so read Artists.txt get next line Daler Mehndi get next folder daler-mehndi-lyrics edit Keywords.txt find _1 replace (all) with Daler Mehndi. Save Changes.

Wondering if something like this is possible? Otherwise it would take me a week to manually do this via copy/pasting or even the replace function in *Notepad++*

I've tried the Macro function in Notepad++ but CTRL-V rather then pasting whats in the clipboard the macro seems to replace the CTRL-V function with whatever text the macro was recorded with has.

So just adding some extra information...

Comment: wait so would you replace `_1` with `Artist 1`, `Song 1` or `Artist 1 - Song 1`?

Comment: So I've added more information and used real examples from these files.

@Monacraft - I would replace _1 with Artist 1 - Song 1

I have added more information with real data in the original post so hope that helps further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Notepad++ installed as my favorite text editor is UltraEdit (shareware).

Although Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service and we expect that the questioner shows us some programming efforts already made to solve a task, it was very easy for me to write the little UltraEdit script for this task and therefore here is an UltraEdit script for this task.

`C:\\Temp\\Test\\` at top of the script must be replaced by path of parent folder for the *lyrics folders. UltraEdit scripts are executed with the JavaScript core engine. Strings in UltraEdit scripts are therefore JavaScript strings where backslash is the escape character. So it is necessary to escape each backslash in parent folder path by one more backslash.

To run this script in UltraEdit, open `Artists.txt` as first file in UltraEdit.

As second file create a new ASCII file with Ctrl+N, copy and paste the lines below into this new file, edit the parent folder path/name in script code and save this script for example with name `KeywordsReplace.js` into any folder.

Now run the script by clicking in menu **Scripting** on command **Run Active Script**.

You can see after script finished in automatically showed output window how many replaces have been made in which `Keywords.txt` files.

```
if (UltraEdit.document.length > 0)  // Is any file opened?
{
   // Parent folder containing all the *lyrics folders.
   var sParentFolder = "C:\\Temp\\Test\\";

   // Define environment for this script.
   UltraEdit.insertMode();
   UltraEdit.columnModeOff();
   // Select everything in first file.
   UltraEdit.document[0].selectAll();

   // Is first file not an empty file?
   if (UltraEdit.document[0].isSel())
   {
      // Determine line terminator type for first file.
      var sLineTerm = "\r\n";
      if (UltraEdit.document[0].lineTerminator == 1) sLineTerm = "\n"
      else if (UltraEdit.document[0].lineTerminator == 2) sLineTerm = "\r"

      // Get all lines of first file into an array of strings
      var asArtists = UltraEdit.document[0].selection.split(sLineTerm);

      // Remove last string if it is empty because file ended with
      // a line termination.
      if (!asArtists[asArtists.length-1].length) asArtists.pop();

      // Define once the parameters for all the replace in files executed
      // below in the loop with changing directory and replace strings.
      UltraEdit.frInFiles.filesToSearch=0;
      UltraEdit.frInFiles.searchSubs=false;
      UltraEdit.frInFiles.ignoreHiddenSubs=false;
      UltraEdit.frInFiles.openMatchingFiles=false;
      UltraEdit.frInFiles.searchInFilesTypes="Keywords.txt";
      UltraEdit.frInFiles.regExp=false;
      UltraEdit.frInFiles.matchCase=true;
      UltraEdit.frInFiles.matchWord=false;
      UltraEdit.frInFiles.logChanges=true;
      UltraEdit.frInFiles.useEncoding=false;
      UltraEdit.frInFiles.preserveCase=false;

      // Run for each artist a replace of all occurrences of _1
      // in the artists lyrics folder by name of the artist.
      for (nArtist = 0; nArtist < asArtists.length; nArtist++)
      {
         // Build folder name by converting artists name to
         // lower case and replacing all spaces by hyphens.
         var sFolder = asArtists[nArtist].toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,"-");
         // Define directory for replace in files by appending
         // additionally the string "-lyrics" to folder name.
         UltraEdit.frInFiles.directoryStart = sParentFolder + sFolder + "-lyrics\\";
         UltraEdit.frInFiles.replace("_1",asArtists[nArtist]);
      }
      // The output window contains the summary information
      // about the replaces made and therefore open it.
      UltraEdit.outputWindow.showWindow(true);
   }
}
```

Script was tested with the provided data with each `Keywords.txt` containing exactly 3 times `_1` in the 6 *lyrics folders. Result of output window was:

```
Running script: C:\Temp\KeywordsReplace.js
============================================================
C:\Temp\Test\butta-mohamed-lyrics\Keywords.txt, 3
3 items replaced in 1 files.
C:\Temp\Test\daler-mehndi-lyrics\Keywords.txt, 3
3 items replaced in 1 files.
C:\Temp\Test\daljit-mattu-lyrics\Keywords.txt, 3
3 items replaced in 1 files.
C:\Temp\Test\darshan-khela-lyrics\Keywords.txt, 3
3 items replaced in 1 files.
C:\Temp\Test\davinder-deep-lyrics\Keywords.txt, 3
3 items replaced in 1 files.
C:\Temp\Test\davinder-deol-lyrics\Keywords.txt, 3
3 items replaced in 1 files.
Script succeeded.
```

In case of downloading and installing UltraEdit is not acceptable for you, you have to wait for another answer providing a batch file solution or a Notepad++ macro solution, or you make the necessary code writing by yourself.

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm :)

I will try and edit the code to cater for other scenarios I have whereby folder name also includes song name. Above code did changes in few seconds compared to me taking a week. So thanks alot for the help.